# interpreting assembly instructions

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to translate the following:

```
Action:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %eax
 subl $0x32, %esp
 movl $0x0, -0x8(%eax)
 movl $0x0, -0x4(%eax)
 movl -0x4(%eax), %eax
 cmpl $0x32(%eax), %ebp
 movl -0x4(%ebp), %eax
 sall $0x2, %ebp
 addl 0x8(%ebp), %ebp
 movl (%ebp), %ebp
 addl %ebp, -0x8(%eax)
 addl $0x1, -0x4(%eax)
```

What is the best way to translate this code?

Comment: Er. Did you kill most of the question on purpose? Those instructions don't exist (you probably mean pushl and movl), and movl needs arguments. You can [rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2794477/revisions) if it was an accident

Comment: Best way to learn assembly language? Read a book.

Answer (score 1):

For the original question:

```
mov     -0x4(%ebp), %eax       # eax = z;
mov     0xc(%ebp), %edx        # edx = y;
mov     (%edx, %eax, 4), %eax  # eax = *(edx + eax + 4)
add     $0x3, %eax             # eax += 3
movb    $0x41, (%eax)          # *eax = 'A'
```

Dry-running the statements give:

```
y[z + 4][3] = 'A';
```